# Modded Server Keeps crashing

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So my friends and I made up a custom modpack for a SMP server. Things were running smoothly at first, but now the server randomly crashes every so often. I've been trying to go through the crash report and server log, but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. I'm a Java programmer, but don't know all the details of the minecraft mod architecture through forge. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the crash report:

```
    Description: Watching Server

java.lang.Error: ServerHangWatchdog detected that a single server tick took 60.00 seconds (should be max 0.05)
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:444)
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:366)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:251)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:145)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:401)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:323)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_150298_a(NBTTagCompound.java:474)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(NBTTagCompound.java:35)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagList.func_74734_a(NBTTagList.java:34)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_150298_a(NBTTagCompound.java:475)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(NBTTagCompound.java:35)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_150298_a(NBTTagCompound.java:475)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(NBTTagCompound.java:35)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.CompressedStreamTools.func_150663_a(CompressedStreamTools.java:112)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.CompressedStreamTools.func_74800_a(CompressedStreamTools.java:102)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.CompressedStreamTools.func_74799_a(CompressedStreamTools.java:47)
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.MapStorage.func_75747_a(SourceFile:95)
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.MapStorage.func_75744_a(SourceFile:78)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_73042_a(WorldServer.java:1053)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_73044_a(WorldServer.java:1000)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71267_a(MinecraftServer.java:408)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:691)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:526)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Server Watchdog
Stacktrace:
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:444)
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:366)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:251)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:145)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:401)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:323)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_150298_a(NBTTagCompound.java:474)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(NBTTagCompound.java:35)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagList.func_74734_a(NBTTagList.java:34)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_150298_a(NBTTagCompound.java:475)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(NBTTagCompound.java:35)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_150298_a(NBTTagCompound.java:475)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound.func_74734_a(NBTTagCompound.java:35)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.CompressedStreamTools.func_150663_a(CompressedStreamTools.java:112)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.CompressedStreamTools.func_74800_a(CompressedStreamTools.java:102)
    at net.minecraft.nbt.CompressedStreamTools.func_74799_a(CompressedStreamTools.java:47)
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.MapStorage.func_75747_a(SourceFile:95)
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.MapStorage.func_75744_a(SourceFile:78)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_73042_a(WorldServer.java:1053)
    at net.minecraft.world.WorldServer.func_73044_a(WorldServer.java:1000)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71267_a(MinecraftServer.java:408)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.func_71217_p(MinecraftServer.java:691)

-- Thread Dump --
Details:
    Threads: "Downloader 8" Id=152 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@3320005
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@3320005
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ...


"AE Compass Service" Id=142 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@df5fe13
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@df5fe13
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #6" Id=137 RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:247)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #5" Id=136 RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:247)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3" Id=125 WAITING on scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool@9ca6b75
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool@9ca6b75
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)


"Chunk I/O Executor Thread-1" Id=123 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@4cc8f428
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@4cc8f428
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #4" Id=119 RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:247)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #3" Id=118 RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:247)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #2" Id=117 RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:247)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"threadDeathWatcher-2-1" Id=113 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.run(ThreadDeathWatcher.java:152)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #1" Id=112 RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:247)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"ic2-poolthread-4" Id=111 WAITING on ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue@5f69f79c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue@5f69f79c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue.take(PriorityExecutor.java:143)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"ic2-poolthread-3" Id=110 WAITING on ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue@5f69f79c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue@5f69f79c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue.take(PriorityExecutor.java:143)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"ic2-poolthread-2" Id=109 WAITING on ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue@5f69f79c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue@5f69f79c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue.take(PriorityExecutor.java:143)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"OpenComputers-SaveHandler-1" Id=108 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@7d4e9f04
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@7d4e9f04
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ...


"Thread-38" Id=107 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at thaumcraft.common.world.aura.AuraThread.run(AuraThread.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Thread-35" Id=104 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at thaumcraft.common.world.aura.AuraThread.run(AuraThread.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Thread-24" Id=93 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at thaumcraft.common.world.aura.AuraThread.run(AuraThread.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Thread-16" Id=85 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at thaumcraft.common.world.aura.AuraThread.run(AuraThread.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"File IO Thread" Id=79 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.ThreadedFileIOBase.func_75736_b(SourceFile:51)
    at net.minecraft.world.storage.ThreadedFileIOBase.run(SourceFile:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Server Watchdog" Id=74 RUNNABLE
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
    at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:454)
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.ServerHangWatchdog.run(ServerHangWatchdog.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"PR RoutingThread #3" Id=73 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2705c21b
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2705c21b
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:549)
    at mrtjp.projectred.transportation.TableUpdateThread.run(router.scala:455)


"PR RoutingThread #2" Id=72 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2705c21b
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2705c21b
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:549)
    at mrtjp.projectred.transportation.TableUpdateThread.run(router.scala:455)


"PR RoutingThread #1" Id=71 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2705c21b
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2705c21b
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:549)
    at mrtjp.projectred.transportation.TableUpdateThread.run(router.scala:455)


"PR RoutingThread #0" Id=70 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2705c21b
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@2705c21b
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:549)
    at mrtjp.projectred.transportation.TableUpdateThread.run(router.scala:455)


"ic2-poolthread-1" Id=69 WAITING on ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue@5f69f79c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue@5f69f79c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at ic2.core.util.PriorityExecutor$FixedPriorityQueue.take(PriorityExecutor.java:143)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"ResearchIOThread" Id=68 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.TaskQueue@2ce70b67
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@2ce70b67
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)


"Ender IO Scheduler" Id=67 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at crazypants.enderio.base.scheduler.Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:41)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #0" Id=51 RUNNABLE
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait0(Native Method)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWait(EpollEventLoop.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:247)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Java2D Disposer" Id=42 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@3c22cc70
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@3c22cc70
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"JLine terminal non blocking reader thread" Id=23 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
    at org.jline.utils.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:270)
    -  locked java.io.FileInputStream@359dc24f
    at org.jline.utils.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:200)
    -  locked java.io.FileInputStream@359dc24f
    at org.jline.utils.NonBlockingReader.run(NonBlockingReader.java:276)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


"Server console handler" Id=22 TIMED_WAITING on org.jline.utils.NonBlockingReader@3c01cbfd
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on org.jline.utils.NonBlockingReader@3c01cbfd
    at org.jline.utils.NonBlockingReader.read(NonBlockingReader.java:174)
    at org.jline.utils.NonBlockingReader.read(NonBlockingReader.java:113)
    at org.jline.keymap.BindingReader.readCharacter(BindingReader.java:132)
    at org.jline.keymap.BindingReader.readBinding(BindingReader.java:109)
    at org.jline.keymap.BindingReader.readBinding(BindingReader.java:60)
    at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readBinding(LineReaderImpl.java:724)
    at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.readLine(LineReaderImpl.java:526)
    ...


"DestroyJavaVM" Id=21 RUNNABLE


"Server thread" Id=19 RUNNABLE
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflateBytes(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:444)
    -  locked java.util.zip.ZStreamRef@28a95329
    at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:366)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:251)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:145)
    -  locked java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream@2c24b00
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    -  locked java.io.BufferedOutputStream@59966ead
    ...


"Server Infinisleeper" Id=18 TIMED_WAITING
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer$1.run(DedicatedServer.java:82)


"Snooper Timer" Id=17 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.TaskQueue@9a82e1c
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.TaskQueue@9a82e1c
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)


"Signal Dispatcher" Id=4 RUNNABLE


"Finalizer" Id=3 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@19a2fe62
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@19a2fe62
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:165)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:216)


"Reference Handler" Id=2 WAITING on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@73ab08fd
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@73ab08fd
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.ServerHangWatchdog.run(ServerHangWatchdog.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `max-tick-time` in your `server.properties` to higher number or `-1`. The format is in milisecounds. Default : `max-tick-time=60000`. Value `-1` makes it do not never crash when tick time is high however it propably means that something highly overloads the server. Remember to restart the server after change :). I hope that helps you. Some googling would also solve the problem :).

Some time ago I run into the same issue and found this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/320b14/server_crashing_can_you_help/